# how to wait for function to execute and then go next javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a 2 function,

inside my `runConfigComplianceDeviceOnClick` I am calling the `getDeviceRunningCompliance` function to get some other data and based on both the results I have to return an object,

But What I am observing my data from the `getDeviceRunningCompliance` (Axios request to get data) function is not returned and it executes next lines,

but when I see in the console value is updated,

How to handle this case,

how to wait for the function to execute and then go next javascript? wanted to deal with asynchronous data then proceed further to the next lines...

```
/**
 * @param {*} graphTable
 */
const runConfigComplianceDeviceOnClick = graphTable => {
    let selectedDevices = graphTable.dTable.store.state.selectedRowsData;
    let paramSelectedDevices;
    let filteredSelectedDevices;
    let finalParam;
    let supportedDevices = true;

    let some = getDeviceRunningCompliance(selectedDevices);
    console.log("getDeviceRunningCompliance some ", some)
    if (some.length) {
        filteredSelectedDevices = selectedDevices.map(function(device, index) {
        console.log("getDeviceRunningCompliance some filteredSelectedDevices", some)
        if (notSupportedFamilies.includes(device.series)) {
            // console.log(i18n.no_support_available_for_aireos);
            supportedDevices = false;
        } else {
            // console.log(i18n.label_configuration_data_not_available);
            supportedDevices = true;
        }

        let valsss = some.find(x => x.id === device.id);
        console.log("valsss ", valsss)
        return {
            id: device.id,
            hostname: device.hostname,
            val: device.complianceStoreStatus.complianceStatus,
            collectionStatus: device.collectionStatus,
            series: device.series,
            supportedDevices: supportedDevices
        };
    });

    finalParam = filteredSelectedDevices.filter(function(val, index) {
        return val.supportedDevices && val.val === "NON_COMPLIANT"; // this should be enable
    });
    paramSelectedDevices = JSON.stringify(finalParam);

    localStorage.setItem("selectedDevicesConfigSync", paramSelectedDevices);
    if (selectedDevices.length !== finalParam.length) {
        toast({
            message: finalParam.length + i18n.device_out_of_sync_for_start_vs_run,
            flavor: "warning",
            label: i18n.toast_header_running_configuration
        });
    }
    shell.router.push(`/dna/provision/configuration-compliance`);
    }
    
};

const getDeviceRunningCompliance = (selectedDevices) => {
    let self = this;
    let deviceRunningComplaince = [];
    selectedDevices.forEach((val, index) => {
        let obj = {};
        getComplianceDetails(val.id).then(data => {
            const complianceDetailsData = data;
            if (complianceDetailsData) {
                // this.setState({
                //  complianceDetailsData: data
                // });
                let cardStatus;
                let complianceApiDataForConfig =
                    complianceDetailsData && complianceDetailsData.filter(config => config.complianceType === "RUNNING_CONFIG");
                cardStatus =
                    complianceApiDataForConfig && complianceApiDataForConfig.length && complianceApiDataForConfig[0].status;
                obj.id = val.id;
                obj.runningStatus = cardStatus;
                deviceRunningComplaince.push(obj);
                // return cardStatus;
            }
        });
        
        // deviceRunningComplaince.push(obj);
    });
    return deviceRunningComplaince;
};
```

Comment: `async`/`await`

Comment: The axios get will return a promise, rather than run synchronously.

Comment: @Andreas anything else other than async await

Comment: `.then()` - But what's wrong with them?

Comment: Try to do something with .then and promise and it's working fine.

Comment: @Andreas & DBS This is how I solved this issue posted an answer.  Please comment if we can do this better. Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved this issue. Please comment if we can do this better.

```
/**
 * @param {*} graphTable
 */
const runConfigComplianceDeviceOnClick = graphTable => {
    let selectedDevices = graphTable.dTable.store.state.selectedRowsData;
    let paramSelectedDevices;
    let filteredSelectedDevices;
    let finalParam;
    let supportedDevices = true;

    getDeviceRunningCompliance(selectedDevices).then(function(some) {
        if (some.length) {
            filteredSelectedDevices = selectedDevices.map(function(device, index) {
                console.log("getDeviceRunningCompliance some filteredSelectedDevices", some);
                if (notSupportedFamilies.includes(device.series)) {
                    // console.log(i18n.no_support_available_for_aireos);
                    supportedDevices = false;
                } else {
                    // console.log(i18n.label_configuration_data_not_available);
                    supportedDevices = true;
                }

                let valsss = some.find(x => x.id === device.id);
                console.log("valsss ", valsss);
                return {
                    id: device.id,
                    hostname: device.hostname,
                    val: device.complianceStoreStatus.complianceStatus,
                    collectionStatus: device.collectionStatus,
                    series: device.series,
                    supportedDevices: supportedDevices
                };
            });

            finalParam = filteredSelectedDevices.filter(function(val, index) {
                return val.supportedDevices && val.val === "NON_COMPLIANT"; // this should be enable
            });
            paramSelectedDevices = JSON.stringify(finalParam);

            localStorage.setItem("selectedDevicesConfigSync", paramSelectedDevices);
            if (selectedDevices.length !== finalParam.length) {
                toast({
                    message: finalParam.length + i18n.device_out_of_sync_for_start_vs_run,
                    flavor: "warning",
                    label: i18n.toast_header_running_configuration
                });
            }
            shell.router.push(`/dna/provision/configuration-compliance`);
        }
    });
};

const getDeviceRunningCompliance = selectedDevices => {
    let promiseData = selectedDevices.map((val, index) => {
        return getComplianceDetails(val.id).then(data => {
            let obj = {};
            const complianceDetailsData = data;
            if (complianceDetailsData) {
                let cardStatus;
                let complianceApiDataForConfig =
                    complianceDetailsData && complianceDetailsData.filter(config => config.complianceType === "RUNNING_CONFIG");
                cardStatus =
                    complianceApiDataForConfig && complianceApiDataForConfig.length && complianceApiDataForConfig[0].status;
                obj.id = val.id;
                obj.runningStatus = cardStatus;
                return obj;
            }
        });
    });
    return Promise.all(promiseData);
};
```